# How to add variable on a set (Alloy)

Tags: time, set, addition, show, alloy

```
module carona

open util/ordering[Time]

sig Time {}

sig Car {
    passengers : set Passager
}

one sig UFCG{
    students: set Student -> Time

}

abstract sig Student{
    region: Region -> Time
}

sig Owner extends Student{
    ownerCar : Car 
}

sig Passager extends Student{
}

abstract sig Region{ }

one sig Norte,Sul,Leste,Oeste,Centro extends Region{ }



fact Owner{
    all o: Owner | #o.ownerCar = 1
}

fact Passager{
    all p:Passager | one p.~passengers  
}

fact Car{
    all c:Car| one c.~ownerCar
    all c:Car| #c.passengers <= 4
    all c:Car| c.passengers.region=(c.~ownerCar).region 

}

fact UFCG {
    all passager: Passager, ufcg : UFCG, t:Time | passager in (ufcg.students).t
    all owner: Owner, ufcg: UFCG,t:Time | owner in (ufcg.students).t
} 

fact Traces{
    init[first]
    all pre: Time-last | let pos = pre.next |
    lone u:UFCG|
    some s:Student|
    addStudent[s,u,pre,pos]
}



pred init[t:Time]{
    one u:UFCG | no (u.students).t 
}



pred addStudent[s:Student, u: UFCG, before, after: Time]{

    (s !in (u.students).before) 
    (u.students).after = (u.students).before + s
}
```

After I run and show the instances created over time, my pred to add Passenger doesn't seem to work, nothing changes or even create. How do i properly add items on a set?

My program, when run, does not show any instance. That is, I can not add anything over time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, in the UFCG fact the first quantified formula says that at every time every passenger is in the UFCG student set, this preventing any change in that set.